# Put Google Map InfoWindow out of Map container

Tags: google-maps, angular9

I am trying to create a map using angular 9 google maps library. In resolutions from 320 to 599, i want my info window container out of map (because my content is such that, it has to come in column view) because it won't fit in the map window. But I am unable  to do so. I am using custom Popups for that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to show InfoWindow outside the Google Maps Div might not be a great idea. I am not sure of how well that would work.

Another solution would be to register a Click event on the google map, and capture that information with an unique ID and pass that information to a box outside the div and display the required data.